# Using FOR loop to eliminate numbers retrieved by array

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<select>
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$q = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE duration='first lecture' and day='Sunday'";
$r = mysql_query($q); 
$ro = mysql_num_rows($r);
if($ro==0) {
for($i=1; $i<=14; $i++) { ?>
<option value=""><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
} }
else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){

for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++)
{
$exclude = array($row['name']);
if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
}
?>          
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use a `FOR LOOP` to eliminate elements retrieved by an array in one loop. 
Suppose `$row` retrieved values `(4,5)`, what I want with that `FOR LOOP` is to display numbers between 1 to 14 except `(4,5)`.

I tried it many times and I succeed in that, but the `loop` in first time eliminate just `(4)` and in second time eliminate just `(5)`.

Is there's a way to eliminate both at one time ?

Comment: Why not make the query not return those rows?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

you might want to change your comparison to:

```
if($row['name'] == $i) continue;
```

---

You're almost there. The only issue is your `in_array($i, $exclude)`. You need to have `$exclude` as an array with the numbers you want in there. Take this for example:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++) {
    $exclude = array(4, 5);
    if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
    echo $i;
}
```

Which returns: `12367891011121314`

---

So you need to modify how you set `$exclude` as `$row['name']` isn't the way to do it.

Also, as a side note, Why don't you do what [chris85 said in the comments and make the query **not** return these rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311693/i-want-for-loop-to-eliminate-numbers-retrieved-by-array/37311763#comment62144322_37311693)

That could be as simple as modifying your SQL query to look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE (duration='first lecture' AND day='Sunday') AND id NOT IN (4,5)
```

Comment: i need $row['name'] because it check for availability of empty rooms range from 1 to 14 so if i select (4,5) it will be static method i need it dynamically

Comment: @EhabAzmi what does `$row['name']` look like? Is it actually a number (`4`/`5`)?

Comment: it's indicate to rooms name not id

Comment: not working still it loop two times and eliminate 4 in first 5 in second

Answer (score 0):

`$row['name']` is probably not an Array. Change:

```
$exclude = array($row['name']);
if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
```

to

```
if(+$row['name'] === $i) continue;
```

Comment: not working still it loop two times and eliminate 4 in first 5 in second